# Instantiating multiple Scenes results in "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

So I have written a Controller that is supposed to navigate between multiple scenes, however, when the second scene is instantiated `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Here is my Controller below with a `View1()` and `View2()` in a single file mre so you can understand what is happening. My goal is just to have multiple screens and multiple models and using a switch case set different scenes on the stage.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Controller extends Application {

    private Scene scene1, scene2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage theStage) {
        this.scene1 = new Scene(new Group(new View1()));
        this.scene2 = new Scene(new Group(new View2()));

        new AnimationTimer() {

            int page = 2;
            @Override
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime){
                // System.out.println(currentNanoTime);
                switch (page){
                    case 2:
                        page = 1;
                        theStage.setScene(scene1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        page = 2;
                        theStage.setScene(scene2);
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        theStage.show();
    }
}

class View1 extends Group {

    public View1() {

        Image img = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/8tcxHWh.jpg");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        getChildren().add(canvas);
    }
}

class View2 extends Group {

    public View2() {

        Image img = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/BF3ty6o.jpg");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        getChildren().add(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you are using the `AnimationTimer` is not logical.

Comment: Also, the `thread.sleep` in the `AnimationTimer`. It's probably better to use a `Timeline`. Well, in this case, `Timeline` is probably also a bad idea

Comment: This logic is constantly loading a Scene.

Comment: I suggest  you find some beginner tutorials and go through a few.

Comment: @Sedrick I thought since the scene was outside of the Animation timer it would only load once. Is there any chance you can help me either via an answer or maybe a paid session on code mentor? I am working on a project for class but the professor never really discussed JavaFX in-depth only that we had to use it. Any help/guidance to help me get multiple scenes structured would be appreciated.

Comment: All of the examples I could find use fxml.load() but we were not supposed to use fxml. It seems easy to switch scenes that way but this just isn't working how I intended.

Comment: @Sedrick The thread.sleep was just to switch the scenes so you could understand where the problem lies. The final program will only be switching to each scene once, and the `AnimationTimer` will only have a `thread.sleep` for around 33 msec.

Comment: I don't have an account with that site. I might take a look at it in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202135/discussion-between-anthony-sette-and-sedrick).

Comment: You should probably be using a button to switch scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest against using `AnimationTimer`. I would suggest you use `Buttons` to load different displays. This app demos one way of using `Buttons` to switch between displays.

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final StackPane mainDisplay = new StackPane();
        final ViewOne viewOne = new ViewOne();
        final ViewTwo viewTwo = new ViewTwo();

        mainDisplay.getChildren().add(viewOne);//Load first view.

        Button btnStageOne = new Button("View One");
        Button btnStageTwo = new Button("View Two");

        btnStageOne.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(!mainDisplay.getChildren().get(0).equals(viewOne))//If sceneone is not loaded, load it.
            {
                 mainDisplay.getChildren().set(0, viewOne);
            }

        });
        btnStageTwo.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if(!mainDisplay.getChildren().get(0).equals(viewTwo))//If scenetwo is not loaded, load it.
            {
                mainDisplay.getChildren().set(0, viewTwo);
            }
        });

        HBox hbButtonPanel = new HBox(btnStageOne, btnStageTwo);
        VBox root = new VBox(mainDisplay, hbButtonPanel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**ViewOne**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public final class ViewOne extends StackPane{
    Label label = new Label();

    public ViewOne() {
        label.setText("Scene One!");
        getChildren().add(label);
    }   
}
```

**ViewTwo**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public final class ViewTwo extends StackPane{
    Label label = new Label();

    public ViewTwo() {
        label.setText("Scene Two!");
        getChildren().add(label);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I think this is missing is that I was using animation timer over short intervals to call the `model.update` and `view.update`. Since this is a game it is important to constantly look for updates.

Comment: I am going to guess that that logic should probably be done in the views. Try to do more and if you run into new problems, ask a new question. I signed up for that site. They have to approve my account.

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: completely unrelated but ... block quotes tags are for ... quotes, not headers ;)